# Highlight word on page with js console command?

Tags: javascript, web, console

I need help with highlighting any word on any webpage using Javascript. Just like searching for words.

I've tried this:
`document.getElementById('Highlightthis').style="background-color:#FFFF00";`
but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Why?

Comment: Please include your html too. Does it do anything? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: It's a tampermonkey script...

Comment: You have to set style attributes individually: `document.getElementById('Highlightthis').style.backgroundColor="#FFFF00";`